# Windows Dell laptop does not automatically reconnect to the Internet

Tags: windows-10, networking, dell-xps

I have a Dell Windows 10 laptop connected to the Internet via a router. Whenever I go away from the laptop and close the lid, then return and open the lid, I find that it is disconnected from the Internet. Sometimes it reconnects automatically after about 30 seconds, but sometimes it does not, and then I have to restart the computer and/or restart the router to make it connect again.

This does not happen with another laptop that is connected to the same router, so the problem is not with the router - it is something with the Dell Windows 10 laptop. What can it be?

EDIT: Here are my network adapters:
[image]

Comment: That can be normal to disconnect on suspend and happens on my laptop. However reconnection should be automatic and not require a reboot.  Laptop.  So, update BIOS, Chipset, all Network cards, restart and try again.